# Parsing a String into List of information KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin, substring

I am an amateur Kotlin programming. And I have one task which I am not sure how to solve.
So any help would come in handy.

**More about this task**:

I get this message via HTTP post request

> AL:OK:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:YY~~TYPE:3~~FOF:v1.0~~RSSI:-68~~PORT:8215~~TEMP:34.22~~CH1:OK~~CH2:KS~~CH3:PR~~CH4:VL~~CH5:KS~~CH6:OK~~AUX1:OK~~AUX2:KS~~AUX3:OK

And I need to parse this message into following output format.

- XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XY - MAC ADDRESS
- 3 - Type of device
- v1.0 - Version of device
- -68 - Signal strenght
- 8215 - Server Port
- 34.22 - Processor temperature

I only need to get this output in console

I would be really thankfull for any kind of help or hints about this problem.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You can use `String.split("~~")` And some destructing declaration to idomatically assign them to their respective variables then split using the colons (`:`)

Comment: please add what you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex group for this purpose and get each part with index. also you can Assign name to each group and then select each part you want with name.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

fun main() {

    val request = "AL:OK:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:YY~~TYPE:3~~FOF:v1.0~~RSSI:-68~~PORT:8215~~TEMP:34.22" +
            "~~CH1:OK~~CH2:KS~~CH3:PR~~CH4:VL~~CH5:KS~~CH6:OK" +
            "~~AUX1:OK~~AUX2:KS~~AUX3:OK"

    extractValues(request)
}

fun extractValues(request: String) {
    val patternWithName = "AL:OK:(?<macAddress>.+)~~TYPE:(?<type>\\d+)~~FOF:(?<fof>v\\d+.\\d+)~~RSSI:(?<rssi>[-+]\\d+)~~PORT:(?<port>\\d+)~~TEMP:(?<temp>\\d+.\\d+)" +
            "~~CH1:(?<ch1>.+)~~CH2:(?<ch2>.+)~~CH3:(?<ch3>.+)~~CH4:(?<ch4>.+)~~CH5:(?<ch5>.+)~~CH6:(?<ch6>.+)" +
            "~~AUX1:(?<aux1>.+)~~AUX2:(?<aux2>.+)~~AUX3:(?<aux3>.+)"

    val patternWithoutName = "AL:OK:(.+)~~TYPE:(\\d+)~~FOF:(v\\d+.\\d+)~~RSSI:([-+]\\d+)~~PORT:(\\d+)~~TEMP:(\\d+.\\d+)" +
            "~~CH1:(.+)~~CH2:(.+)~~CH3:(.+)~~CH4:(.+)~~CH5:(.+)~~CH6:(.+)" +
            "~~AUX1:(.+)~~AUX2:(.+)~~AUX3:(.+)"

    val matcher = Pattern.compile(patternWithoutName).matcher(request)

    if (matcher.find()) {
        // get with their name --> use [patternWithName]
        // val macAddress = matcher.group("macAddress")
        // val type = matcher.group("type")
        // val fof = matcher.group("fof")

        // or
        // get with index -- use [patternWithName] or [patternWithoutName]
        for (i in 1..matcher.groupCount()) {
            println(matcher.group(i))
        }
    } else {
        error("$request doesn't match.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This also brings out a solution that I can use.Much appreciated!